# there was a code given in my text book about finding the avg between 3 no. works in blueJ but not in intelliJ. how do i use this code in intelliJ?

Tags: java

Why doesn't this work in IntelliJ?

```
public class main {
    public static void main(int A, int B, int C){
        int sum = 0;
        double avg = 0.0;
        sum = (A+B+C);
        avg = (double)sum/3.0;
        System.out.println("the sum ="+ sum);
        System.out.println("the average = "+ avg);

    }
}
```

Comment: Too much generic; why don't you post at least the error you got

Comment: While in this it is clear what the problem is, for the future please add a bit more explanation. "Doesn't work" is not something that helps people understand how they can help you. Next time please be sure to include error messages (if any), expected inputs, expected output, etc. Please read [ask]